# How to increase the speed of transfer of data from android to arduino in bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, robotics, arduino-ide

I'm trying to use an android app to do the processing of a path finding algorithm for a robot using Bluetooth. But currently, it takes 1 or 2 seconds for the transfer to complete, so that there is an output in the Arduino. Is there a way to minimise this to make the transfer-output instant?

This kind of delay is causing problems such as stopping instantly when an obstacle is detected. Is there any better way of doing this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple solutions worked for me:-

1. Increase the delay to 50 - 100 milliseconds.
2. Add this after the `Serial.begin(9600)` in `setup()`;

   ```
   Serial.setTimeout(50);
   ```

Step two is the most important. It worked for me only after I added the above code. This is not mentioned very often in many other forums that I have looked when I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which device you are using. I assume that you connected the Bluetooth chip set to UART port(As in arduino Uno), In that case the slowest part in whole communication is the serial interface between Arduino and Bluetooth chip set. Check what baud rate you are using and can it increase further. I think default will be 9600 which is only around 960 bytes per second. Set the maximum baud rate supported by your device and the Bluetooth chip.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't, bluetooth is laggy like that. If you instead had your path finding algorithm on the arduino board itself, you could avoid the issue. You can also try adding a delay to your arduino code, because it is possible that the arduino is sending messages repeatedly without taking into account the lag that bluetooth has.

Comment: Bluetooth speed is 25Mbps from bluetooth 3.0. I don't think that is laggy for a micro controller.

Comment: lag is about latency, not data volume. Bluetooth always has a delay because of the high latency.

Comment: though some bluetooth,  BLE, claims latency of just 6 ms. I am certain most bluetooth has a much higher latency.

Comment: I always use BLE for my projects, whenever possible.